# Can you make subclipse create a folder structure when sharing a project?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, directory-structure

When in eclipse and you decide to share a project in a subversion repository using subclipse, can you make it create a folder structure for that project automagically somehow?

What I want is for every shared project to add this kind of structure:

/Client/Project/branches
/Client/Project/tags
/Client/Project/trunk/EclipseProject

Where Client is the name of the client, Project is the name of the actual project and EclipseProject is the name of the project as it exists in Eclipse. There may be more than one EclipseProject in this structure, in which case of course the directories doesn't have to be created.

Is this possible to do with a subclipse or am I better off writing a simple shell-script to do this? My first thought was doing a shell script since I don't mind using the terminal, but some of my collegues really don't like command line interfaces but dig Subclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot easily extend Subclipse to make it generate such a structure.

Actually, Subclipse had an issue with the [GUI representation of deep structures](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=817), only fixed in the latest version 1.4.7 (05 December 2008), so there are not yet to provide any "template structure" ;) They try to represent *existing* folder trees right.

The only feature which does *automatically* create folders would be the "[Create any intermediate folders that are missing](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=644)" checkbox to Branch/Tag dialog, to make any missing and required parent directories as part of the transaction during a mkdir/move/copy commands.

That's about it.

Comment: That's what I thought then. Thanks!